# iOS webapp loading-image not showing up

Tags: html, ios

So, below you can find the code I have in my header.

When I save this as a webapp to my homescreen and I open it from there, a loading screen shoul appear...

at the iPad 2 both portrait and landscape mode are working like a charm.

But not on my 4s...

any thoughts?

edit: and yes, I did check the image sizes and dpi etc.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 320px)" href="../img/ios/startup320x460.png" /> <!-- iPhone -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 320px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="../img/ios/startup640x960png.png" /> <!-- iPhone Retina -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait)" href="../img/ios/startup768x1004.png" /> <!-- iPad Portrait -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape)" href="../img/ios/startup1024x748.png" /> <!-- iPad Landscape -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="../img/ios/startup1536x2008.png" /> <!-- iPad Landscape Retina -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="../img/ios/startup1496x2048.png" /> <!-- iPad Landscape Retina -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If your filenames do represent the image sizes, then your iPhone retina image is sized 640 x 960 pixels, while it should be 640 x 920. iOS is *very* picky about that.

Comment: You're right, but the image itself is 640 wide x 920 high with 72dpi saved as a png via the 'save for web' in Photoshop...

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code. Have you tried using something like WireShark or Fiddler to see if your iPhone is actually requesting the startup image?